# Connect desktop wifi chip onto raspberry pi 2?

Tags: raspbian, wifi, pi-2

Is there a way I can connect a desktop wifi chip to my raspberry pi two? Just for clarification, not the usb adapter but an actual wifi chip.

Comment: What connections does the desktop wifi chip provide?

Comment: Unfortunately, I do not have the wifi chip with me. But, what connections would the pi allow?

Comment: I am not aware of any.  I do know someone hacked a Pi Zero to attach a wifi chip directly to some pads.

Comment: @joan Technically that hack still involved USB.

Comment: @Martin Your connection options are SPI, GPIO shield, and the almighty USB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're just interested in attaching a non-USB WiFi device, you may want to take a look at an ESP8266 WiFi module (or chip).

In fact, there is an Instructable guide just for that: http://www.instructables.com/id/Connect-an-ESP8266-to-your-RaspberryPi/

Note: It's not that great for full-blown WiFi comms. Maybe serial.